# Where to store key-store certificate in Spring Boot if not in the class path to reuse the microservice docker image

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a set of microservices in Spring Boot. They use spring security key-store configuration for oAuth and I build them using gradle as docker images. Than I run those images in multiple projects.
I use the configuration I find in every example to add it in the classpath (which effectively is adding the pkcs12 file in my src/main/resources dir so gradle builds the Spring boot archive ok)

My problem is that as mentioned, I reuse those microservices in different scopes (dev/QA/production) and in different applications as I code in a very generic way, so I can reuse the microservices without touching one line of code.

I would like not to use the same certificate in all my projects and environments (so for example a coder that works in dev does not know which is the certificate used in production). I wonder what would be the approach to place the pkcs12 file so that it is not part of the project it self, so when I deploy my microservice I would not do:

```
key-store: classpath:mycert.pkcs12
```

but something like

```
key-store: someCertificateStorageSystemNotInTheMicroserviceJarOrClasspath:mycert.pkcs12
```

I know I can add the certificate file using a build parameter when I build the microservice docker image and then reference it with an absolute path in the key-store configuration but I wonder if there is a better practice or recommended approach better than that to avoid including the same certificate(s) in the jar file.